# C program on Linux to get camera photo

Tags: c, linux, camera, linux-device-driver

So I was wondering what can I do to get a photo from my Logitech C270 camera? I have posted my code below, it seems that the file pointed to by camera is empty because the starting and ending address is the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 307200 // number of pixels (640x480 for my webcam)
int main() {
//create files
    FILE *camera, *grab;
    camera=fopen("/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-046d_0825_1155F490-video-index0", "rb");

//testing files

if(camera==NULL){fputs("\n Can't open camera!",stderr);}

if(feof(camera)){fputs("\n End of file reached!",stderr);}

if(ferror(camera)){fputs("\n The camera has an error!",stderr);}

//stats
rewind (camera); //set position indicator at begining of file
printf("%p is the pos of pointer start\n",&camera); //starting address 
fseek(camera,0,SEEK_END);//set position indicator to EndOfFile
printf("%p is the pos of pointer end\n",&camera); //ending address

//running
    grab=fopen("grab.raw", "wb");
    float data[SIZE];
    int n=2; //arbitrary non 0 num to test if fread = 0
    n=fread(data, sizeof(data[0]), SIZE, camera);
if(n=0){perror(ERRNO);}
    printf(" %d is the state of fread \n",n);  //fread's value
    fwrite(data, sizeof(data[0]), SIZE, grab);
    fclose(camera);
    fclose(grab); 
    return 0;
}
```

None of the text from //testing files comes up, I just get the fact that fread() is 0 and I get the starting and ending address to be the same. What does this mean?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you shouldn't read the file directly, but instead use V4L.

Comment: 1. The frames can come encoded in a given format from the camera. 2. Use OpenCV and avoid the trouble. Yes and as @user4098326 commented you need to use `ioctl()`'s for V4L devices instead of reading from the file directly anyway.

Comment: Trying to create an executable and do some socket programming on an OpenWrt device, trying to avoid using OpenCV. Ill try looking into Video 4 linux and using ioctl() Thnx!

Comment: Look at http://git.ideasonboard.org/?o=age for project `yavta` (most probably this one you need) and http://git.linuxtv.org/cgit.cgi/v4l-utils.git/ for `media-ctl`.

Comment: feof() is only valid AFTER trying to read past the end of a file.  so feof() will tell you nothing in the above code.   A camera does not return float values, it returns bytes/characters, the aggrate of which is the formatted image.  so trying to return the 'pixel count' number of floats will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files in a camera are very similar to the files on your computer.

There is a top level directory (and usually) two directories below that.

Where any video/pictures are in the bottom most directory.

The files in the camera are not a raw binary file containing only the image.

Rather, they are formatted (pictures are usually .jpg files and movies are usually mpg3 or mpg4)

the upper level directories are (usually) a single entry, so size will read 0.

If you access the camera with a file browser, you will see the directory structure.

Your code needs to follow the camera file structure.

When the code gets to an actual image or movie, it can check the file name extension to determine what to do next.

stat() will return the details about the file, including its' size.

That stat() information can/should be used to allocate enough memory for the file.

Then the file can be read into the resulting memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is that your checking the address in memory of the FILE type camera. What you should be printing is fpos(camera). I dunno much about what you doing, but the image maybe a non-positional stream more like a pipe than a normal disk file. You should also check the return code from rewind and fseek to see if they fail to verify the situation.
The reason fread is 0 is because you fail to rewind camera after you have positioned the file pointer to SEEK_END